# Testing route in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, routes

I have a Rails 3.0 web app that allow user to create own path to the application.

```
example : www.my_app.com/user_company_name
```

So I store a custom path in user DB field. User can changing path throught a input.

I have added this validation in model

```
validates_presence_of :custom_page
validates_format_of :custom_page, :with => /^([a-z]|[0-9]|\-|_)+$/, :message => "Only letter (small caps), number, underscore and - are authorized"
validates_length_of :custom_page, :minimum => 3
validates_uniqueness_of :custom_page, :case_sensitive => false
```

But I don't know how I can validate url to check it isn't in conflict with another route in my routing.

For example in my route.rb I have

```
resources :user
```

Validation need to don't allow using www.my_app.com/user, how I can do that?

Thanks, vincent

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, you match the company name to a variable

```
match 'some_path/:company_name.format'
```

you can then do the lookup using company_name which rails will populate for you.

Validating the uniqueness of the custom_page variable should be enough to ensure there's no overlap.  (note that validate uniqueness of doesn't scale -- if this will be big, you need a db constraint as well) as long as users can only specify one field.

If you're letting users specify

```
'some_path/:custom_path_1/:custom_path_2.format'
```

then you have to validate across both fields, and now it's getting messy.  Hope you're not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a custom validation to weed out "user"

```
validate :custom_page_cant_be_user

def custom_page_cant_be_user
  errors.add(:custom_page, "can't be `user`") if self.custom_page =~ /^user$/i

end
```

assuming `:custom_page` comes in as a basic `[a-z]`, if `:custom_page` has `/user` you need to update the regex a bit.